# Creating a Button with a round background color Java

Tags: java, jbutton

I have the following button:

```
    JButton S1L1Reset = new JButton("Reset");
    S1L1Reset.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    S1L1Reset.setForeground(new Color(90, 90, 90));
    S1L1Reset.setBackground(new Color(220, 208, 192));
    S1L1Reset.setOpaque(true);
```

I would like for the button to be round instead of boxed. I found another post that created a class that can make the border of the button round which is shown below.

```
class RoundedBorder implements Border {

     private int radius;

     RoundedBorder(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
     }

    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return new Insets(this.radius+1, this.radius+1, this.radius+2, this.radius);
    }

    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        return true;
    }

    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        g.drawRoundRect(x, y, width-1, height-1, radius, radius);
    }
}
```

When I make the changes to the button, to utilize this class, I get the following code:

```
    JButton S1L1Reset = new JButton("Reset");
    S1L1Reset.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    S1L1Reset.setForeground(new Color(90, 90, 90));
    S1L1Reset.setBackground(new Color(220, 208, 192));
    S1L1Reset.setOpaque(true);
    S1L1Reset.setBorderPainted(false);
    S1L1Reset.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20)); //new line of code added
```

The code however creates a button that looks like the following: [Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrIjY.png). Is there any way that I can format the button such that the background color also remains within the round border.

Entire Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class TestEnvironment {

JFrame TestEnvironmentWindow;

Vector data1 = new Vector(100);
Vector data2 = new Vector(100);
Vector data3 = new Vector(100);
JTable S1L1;
JTable S1L2;
JTable S1L3;

private DefaultTableModel dataModel1;
private DefaultTableModel dataModel2;
private DefaultTableModel dataModel3;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                TestEnvironment window = new TestEnvironment();
                window.TestEnvironmentWindow.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public TestEnvironment() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {

    TestEnvironmentWindow = new JFrame();
    TestEnvironmentWindow.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    TestEnvironmentWindow.setResizable(false);
    TestEnvironmentWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    TestEnvironmentWindow.setTitle("Statistics Tool Kit");
    TestEnvironmentWindow.setIconImage(null);
    TestEnvironmentWindow.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 650));

//  Content Section

    final TableModel dataModel = new AbstractTableModel() {

        public int getColumnCount(){ 
            return 5; 
        }

        public int getRowCount(){ 
            return 10;
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col){ 
            return new Integer(row*col); 
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col){
            return true; 
        }
    };

    JPanel Content = new JPanel();
    Content.setBounds(175, 0, 825, 605);
    TestEnvironmentWindow.getContentPane().add(Content);
    Content.setBackground(new Color(244,244,244));
    Content.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    Content.add(tabbedPane);
    JPanel set1Panel = new JPanel();
    set1Panel.setLayout(null);

    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>(2);
    columnNames.addElement("X-Values");
    columnNames.addElement("Y-Values");

    S1L1 = new JTable(data1, columnNames);
    S1L1.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    S1L1.setGridColor(new Color(150,150,150));
    JScrollPane S1L1Scroll = new JScrollPane(S1L1,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    S1L1Scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize (new Dimension(0,0));
    dataModel1 = new DefaultTableModel(data1, columnNames);
    S1L1.setModel(dataModel1);
    S1L1Scroll.setBounds(38, 50, 225, 400);
    set1Panel.add(S1L1Scroll);

    S1L2 = new JTable(data2, columnNames);
    S1L2.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    S1L2.setGridColor(new Color(150,150,150));
    JScrollPane S1L2Scroll = new JScrollPane(S1L2,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    S1L2Scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize (new Dimension(0,0));
    dataModel2 = new DefaultTableModel(data2, columnNames);
    S1L2.setModel(dataModel2);
    S1L2Scroll.setBounds(288, 50, 225, 400);
    set1Panel.add(S1L2Scroll);

    S1L3 = new JTable(data3, columnNames);
    S1L3.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    S1L3.setGridColor(new Color(150,150,150));
    JScrollPane S1L3Scroll = new JScrollPane(S1L3,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    S1L3Scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize (new Dimension(0,0));
    dataModel3 = new DefaultTableModel(data3, columnNames);
    S1L3.setModel(dataModel3);
    S1L3Scroll.setBounds(538, 50, 225, 400);
    set1Panel.add(S1L3Scroll);

    JLabel ListOneLabel = new JLabel("List 1");
    ListOneLabel.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    ListOneLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    ListOneLabel.setBackground(new Color(220, 208, 192));
    ListOneLabel.setOpaque(true);
    ListOneLabel.setBounds(77, 20, 150, 20);
    set1Panel.add(ListOneLabel);

    JLabel ListTwoLabel = new JLabel("List 2");
    ListTwoLabel.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    ListTwoLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    ListTwoLabel.setBackground(new Color(220, 208, 192));
    ListTwoLabel.setOpaque(true);
    ListTwoLabel.setBounds(327, 20, 150, 20);
    set1Panel.add(ListTwoLabel);

    JLabel ListThreeLabel = new JLabel("List 3");
    ListThreeLabel.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    ListThreeLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    ListThreeLabel.setBackground(new Color(220, 208, 192));
    ListThreeLabel.setOpaque(true);
    ListThreeLabel.setBounds(577, 20, 150, 20);
    set1Panel.add(ListThreeLabel);

    JButton S1L1Reset = new JButton("Reset");
    S1L1Reset.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    S1L1Reset.setForeground(new Color(90, 90, 90));
    S1L1Reset.setBackground(new Color(220, 208, 192));
    S1L1Reset.setOpaque(true);
    S1L1Reset.setBorderPainted(false);
    S1L1Reset.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20));
    S1L1Reset.setBounds(43, 465, 100, 20);
    set1Panel.add(S1L1Reset);
    S1L1Reset.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            S1L1Reset.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));

        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            S1L1Reset.setForeground(new Color(90,90,90));
        }
    });
    S1L1Reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            deleteAllRows(dataModel1);
        }
    });
    S1L1Reset.setUI(new BasicButtonUI() {
        public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            if (c.isOpaque()) {
                Color fillColor = c.getBackground();
                g.setColor(fillColor);
                g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(),c.getHeight(), 20, 20);
            }
            paint(g, c);
        }
    });

    JButton S1L2Reset = new JButton("Reset");
    S1L2Reset.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    S1L2Reset.setForeground(new Color(90, 90, 90));
    S1L2Reset.setBackground(new Color(220, 208, 192));
    S1L2Reset.setOpaque(true);
    S1L2Reset.setBorderPainted(false);
    S1L2Reset.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20));
    S1L2Reset.setBounds(293, 465, 100, 20);
    set1Panel.add(S1L2Reset);
    S1L2Reset.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            S1L2Reset.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            S1L2Reset.setForeground(new Color(90,90,90));
        }
    });
    S1L2Reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            deleteAllRows(dataModel2);
        }
    }); 
    S1L2Reset.setUI(new BasicButtonUI() {
        public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            if (c.isOpaque()) {
                g.setColor(c.getBackground());
                g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(),c.getHeight(), 20, 20);
            }
            paint(g, c);
        }
    });

    JButton S1L3Reset = new JButton("Reset");
    S1L3Reset.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    S1L3Reset.setForeground(new Color(90, 90, 90));
    S1L3Reset.setBackground(new Color(220, 208, 192));
    S1L3Reset.setOpaque(true);
    S1L3Reset.setBorderPainted(false);
    S1L3Reset.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20));
    S1L3Reset.setBounds(543, 465, 100, 20);
    set1Panel.add(S1L3Reset);
    S1L3Reset.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            S1L3Reset.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            S1L3Reset.setForeground(new Color(90,90,90));
        }
    });
    S1L3Reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    }); 
    S1L3Reset.setUI(new BasicButtonUI() {
        public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            if (c.isOpaque()) {
                g.setColor(c.getBackground());
                g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(),c.getHeight(), 20, 20);
            }
            paint(g, c);
        }
    });

    JButton S1L1Save = new JButton("Save");
    S1L1Save.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    S1L1Save.setForeground(new Color(90, 90, 90));
    S1L1Save.setBackground(new Color(220, 208, 192));
    S1L1Save.setOpaque(true);
    S1L1Save.setBorderPainted(false);
    S1L1Save.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20));
    S1L1Save.setBounds(155, 465, 100, 20);
    set1Panel.add(S1L1Save);
    S1L1Save.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            S1L1Save.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            S1L1Save.setForeground(new Color(90,90,90));
        }
    });
    S1L1Save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    }); 
    S1L1Save.setUI(new BasicButtonUI() {
        public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            if (c.isOpaque()) {
                g.setColor(c.getBackground());
                g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(),c.getHeight(), 20, 20);
            }
            paint(g, c);
        }
    });

    JButton S1L2Save = new JButton("Save");
    S1L2Save.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    S1L2Save.setForeground(new Color(90, 90, 90));
    S1L2Save.setBackground(new Color(220, 208, 192));
    S1L2Save.setOpaque(true);
    S1L2Save.setBorderPainted(false);
    S1L2Save.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20));
    S1L2Save.setBounds(405, 465, 100, 20);
    set1Panel.add(S1L2Save);
    S1L2Save.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            S1L2Save.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            S1L2Save.setForeground(new Color(90,90,90));
        }
    });
    S1L2Save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    }); 
    S1L2Save.setUI(new BasicButtonUI() {
        public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            if (c.isOpaque()) {
                g.setColor(c.getBackground());
                g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(),c.getHeight(), 20, 20);
            }
            paint(g, c);
        }
    });

    JButton S1L3Save = new JButton("Save");
    S1L3Save.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    S1L3Save.setForeground(new Color(90, 90, 90));
    S1L3Save.setBackground(new Color(220, 208, 192));
    S1L3Save.setOpaque(true);
    S1L3Save.setBorderPainted(false);
    S1L3Save.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20));
    S1L3Save.setBounds(655, 465, 100, 20);
    set1Panel.add(S1L3Save);
    S1L3Save.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            S1L3Save.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            S1L3Save.setForeground(new Color(90,90,90));
        }
    });
    S1L3Save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });     
    S1L3Save.setUI(new BasicButtonUI() {
        public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            if (c.isOpaque()) {
                g.setColor(c.getBackground());
                g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(),c.getHeight(), 20, 20);
            }
            paint(g, c);
        }
    });

    JButton ClearAll = new JButton("Clear All");
    ClearAll.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    ClearAll.setForeground(new Color(90, 90, 90));
    ClearAll.setBackground(new Color(220, 208, 192));
    ClearAll.setOpaque(true);
    ClearAll.setBorderPainted(false);
    ClearAll.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20));
    ClearAll.setBounds(238, 515, 150, 25);
    set1Panel.add(ClearAll);
    ClearAll.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            ClearAll.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            ClearAll.setForeground(new Color(90,90,90));
        }
    });
    ClearAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    }); 
    ClearAll.setUI(new BasicButtonUI() {
        public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            if (c.isOpaque()) {
                g.setColor(c.getBackground());
                g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(),c.getHeight(), 20, 20);
            }
            paint(g, c);
        }
    });

    JButton SaveAll = new JButton("Save All");
    SaveAll.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    SaveAll.setForeground(new Color(90, 90, 90));
    SaveAll.setBackground(new Color(220, 208, 192));
    SaveAll.setOpaque(true);
    SaveAll.setBorderPainted(false);
    SaveAll.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20));
    SaveAll.setBounds(410, 515, 150, 25);
    set1Panel.add(SaveAll);
    SaveAll.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            SaveAll.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            SaveAll.setForeground(new Color(90,90,90));
        }
    });
    SaveAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    }); 
    SaveAll.setUI(new BasicButtonUI() {
        public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            if (c.isOpaque()) {
                g.setColor(c.getBackground());
                g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(),c.getHeight(), 20, 20);
            }
            paint(g, c);
        }
    });

    tabbedPane.add(set1Panel);

//  Menu Bar Section
    JPanel MenuBar = new JPanel();
    MenuBar.setBackground(new Color(220, 208, 192));
    MenuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 175, 605);
    TestEnvironmentWindow.getContentPane().add(MenuBar);
    MenuBar.setLayout(null);

//  Menu Bar Section    
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    TestEnvironmentWindow.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    JMenu mnEdit = new JMenu("Edit");
    menuBar.add(mnEdit);

    JMenu mnSearch = new JMenu("Search");
    menuBar.add(mnSearch);

    JMenu mnWindow = new JMenu("Window");
    menuBar.add(mnWindow);

    JMenu mnHelp = new JMenu("Help");
    menuBar.add(mnHelp);
}

public static void deleteAllRows(final DefaultTableModel model) {
    for( int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
        model.removeRow(i);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: so you want the edges to be rounded??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swing component uses UI delegate to draw itself, the background painting is done in the base class ComponentUI like this:

```
public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
    if (c.isOpaque()) {
        g.setColor(c.getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(),c.getHeight());
    }
    paint(g, c);
}
```

As you can see it uses fillRect so it must fill the background rectangularly. To change it, create a subclass of BasicButtonUI (whose subclasses are UI delegate of various look & feels) and override this method by filling round rect instead:

```
    S1L1Reset.setUI(new BasicButtonUI() {
        @Override
        public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            if (c.isOpaque()) {
                Color fillColor = c.getBackground();

                AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) c;
                ButtonModel model = button.getModel();

                if (model.isPressed()) {
                    fillColor = fillColor.darker();
                } else if (model.isRollover()) {
                    fillColor = fillColor.brighter();
                }

                g.setColor(fillColor);
                g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(),c.getHeight(), 20, 20);
            }
            paint(g, c);
        }
    });
```

As you can see in the code, you'll need to handle various states of the button like mouse pressed background because these are done in the BasicButtonUI subclasses, since you no longer using these subclasses, you'll have to implement all that by yourself. You may reference MetalButtonUI for an example of how a button paints itself under different states in the Metal look & feel.

And maybe the call to setBorderPainted(false) is not needed? If you really want to utilize the round border you should need it to be painted.

[image: The round button in action!]

Comment: How would I setup the various states of the button as you have said. I have setup a MouseListener and an ActionListener for the button. In the Mouse listener I have set up mouseEntered and mouseExited. What would I do from here. Also thank you very much for the help again.

Comment: Hi Mathew, you don't need to add mouse listener yourself (in my initial answer I said you need to add listener by yourself but soon I remember it is not required, the superclass has done this for you), you just need to check the state in the button model and paint according to the interested states. I have updated my answer to show how it is done (the use of brighter/darker is just an example, you can change them to arbitrary colors).

Comment: Whenever I place my mouse over the button, it goes back to a square shape. If I remove my mouse from the button it remains a square shape. When I leave the GUI window and open something else up like google chrome and the go back to the GUI window, the buttons reset to a round shape. Why is this the case?

Comment: Hi Mathew, can you post the complete program? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the original post with the entire code at the end. You can copy paste it into a .java file and it should be runnable as long as the class name is the same as the file name.

Comment: Sorry, since I only tested in Linux before so I didn't recognize this problem. Now I can repeat the problem you said in Windows.

To fix this, you need to set all the round buttons' opaque to false instead of true. It is because the round button does not paint all pixels within its rectangular bounds.

Comment: From the Component's isOpaque() method documentation:

     * An opaque component paints every pixel within its
     * rectangular region. A non-opaque component paints only some of
     * its pixels, allowing the pixels underneath it to "show through".

And therefore within your update() method of the button UI subclass, you need to remove the check to c.isOpaque() otherwise no round rect will be filled.

Comment: So I would have S1L1Save.setOpaque(true); set to S1L1Save.setOpaque(false); and I would remove the if statement that tests if c.isOpaque? If this is the case then the button color is not visible. Also I use a mac if this makes a difference. Thank you so much for your help again. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You just remove the isOpaque() test but not the whole if block, right? And try to print something after the fillRoundRect statement to see if it get executed at all?

Comment: What should I test for instead in the if block?

Comment: No need for the if block, just call fillRoundRect directly.

Comment: Just ensure you know the fillRoundRect method call get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Just adjust the width and height of class RoundButton as well as corner in the method of [setRoundRect(double a, double y, double w, double h, double arcWidth, double arcHeight)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html)

class RoundButton extends JButton {

```
    public RoundButton(String label) {
        super(label);
        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = size.height = Math.max(size.width,size.height);
        setPreferredSize(size);

        setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (getModel().isArmed()) {
            g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
        } else {
            g.setColor(getBackground());
        }
        g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, 250, 50, 40, 40);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(getForeground());
        g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 250, 50, 10, 10); 
    }

    Shape shape;
    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
        if (shape == null || 
                !shape.getBounds().equals(getBounds())) {
            shape = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, 250, 50,10,10);
        }
        return shape.contains(x, y);
    }

}
```

To use that class ex

```
JButton a = new RoundButton("ABC");
a.setBounds(400,0,250,50);
a.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
a.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
a.setFont(new Font("Roboto", Font.BOLD, 15));
panel.add(a);
```